# Python: How to search a list from the middle outwards instead of searching from left to right like default?

Tags: python, list

My list looks like this
list = ["a","b","c","b","a","c","b"]
and I want to be able to search from the middle index outwards to find the first available "a". Using this logic it should search from index 3 then search indexes 2 and 4, then search indexes 1 and 5 then finally search indexes 0 and 6. If we apply this logic to our list, we search the list at index3 for "a" and it doesn't work, so we search indexes2 and 4 for "a" and we find it at index4

I tried using list.index("a") but that just returns the first available "a" at index0 when in reality I want the "a" at index4 since it is the closest to index3. I'm sorry if the answer is obvious, I am new to python and want to be able to search lists like this for a project of mine

I think I know a solution is to be able to start the search at index3 in the right direction and to also start a simultaneous search at index 3 in the left direction but I have no clue how to search in the left direction

EDIT: is there also a way to make it work if the middle is offset?

Comment: but why tho?...

Comment: but why not tho ?...
Did you try splitting your list in two halves (or more/non even sublist), then searching on each sublist in the order you want :) ?

Comment: What does "the middle is offset" mean?

Comment: @SamiTahri i guess because there's not an obvious advantage to doing it this way

Comment: you iterate i from 0 to len(list)//2, and then you can do `list[middleIndex + i]` to iterate right and `list[middleIndex - i]` to iterate left. you will need to fine tune the last elements since the middleIndex might not be exactly in the middle if your list has an even number of elements.

Comment: @SuperStew well it can be, it just depends on what you're data looks like, and what you problem is. Assuming you have some information about the distribution of events, searching in this way can be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some good old math to get the middle element of the list.

```
mylist =  ["a","b","c","b","a","c","b"]
middle_index = (len(mylist) -1) / 2 # -1 since lists start at 0
middle_index = round(middle_index) # use round() if the list is even and middle_index variable is a float.

for index in range(middle_index): # loop over half the list
    value1 = mylist[middle_index-index] # get the variable left of the index
    value2 = mylist[middle_index+index] # get the variable right of the index
    if value1 == is "a":
        print("found!")
    if value2 == is "a":
        print("found!")
```